# How to add one border line for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to add border line between 2 UIView, as i researched, the following code can add 4 borders.

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 5.0f;    
self.imgview.frame = CGRectInset(self.imgview. frame, -borderWidth, -borderWidth);
self.imgview. layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.imgview. layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
```

However, i just need to add one border, any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one One more UIView (BorderView) between two UIView (View1 and View2). Give the border view appropriate width and background color.[image]

Comment: That is the worst thing to do, you allocated another object to put a single line!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set these borders programmatically, you can use the following snippet of code

```
+(void)SetImageViewBottomBorder :(UIImageView *)imageView{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
    border.borderColor = [[self colorWithHexString:@"9B9B9B"] CGColor];
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, imageView.frame.size.height - borderWidth,    imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [imageView.layer addSublayer:border];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled  = YES;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

you can replace the UIImageView with UIView and it will be working like a charm.

Comment: I followed your advice, how can I implent the class method inside view controller, can I use instance method instead?

Comment: You can, I have implemented this class method in a UI helper as it is used in many view controllers. So, you can use instance method it will not cause any problem.